# How to run selected Python codes using SublimeREPL

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have set up the sublimeREPL and can run a .py file using Command + B with no problem. However, I was wondering how to run selected lines of codes only instead of the whole file.

On https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL, it says that SublimeREPL supports "Quickly run selected script." But how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `SublimeREPL` following [guide](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#installation) on their GitHub repository.

Create or open your *python* script. Then, using Command Palette, type *SublimeREPL: Python* and select it. It should open a Python REPL.

They listed shortcuts for running parts of python file at their [documentation](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#documentation), but I'll also list them here:

- <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>  -> Evaluate in REPL **selection**
- <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd>  -> Evaluate in REPL **file**
- <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>(*L*)  -> Evaluate in REPL **line**
- <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>  -> Evaluate in REPL **block** of code

Note: <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> means:

1. press *Ctrl* and *Comma*
2. release all
3. press *s*.

In the example below, I ran 3 `print` statements by selecting them and by pressing <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> shortcut:

[image: Sublime REPL run lines]